# How do I run SQL SELECT on AWS Glue created Dataframe in Spark?

Tags: scala, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I have the following job in AWS Glue which basically reads data from one table and extracts it as a csv file in S3, however I want to run a query on this table (A Select, SUM and GROUPBY) and want to get that output to CSV, how do I do this in AWS Glue? I am a newbie in Spark so please help

```
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = 
"db1", table_name = "dbo1_expdb_dbo_stg_plan", transformation_ctx = 
"datasource0")

applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = 
[("plan_code", "int", "plan_code", "int"), ("plan_id", "int", "plan_id", 
"int")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")

datasink2 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = 
applymapping1, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": 
"s3://bucket"}, format = "csv", transformation_ctx = "datasink2")
job.commit()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog" function of glue context creates a dynamic frame and not dataframe. And dynamic frame does not support execution of sql queries.

To execute sql queries you will first need to convert the dynamic frame to dataframe, register a temp table in spark's memory and then execute the sql query on this temp table.

***Sample code:***

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())
spark_session = glueContext.spark_session
sqlContext = SQLContext(spark_session.sparkContext, spark_session)

DyF = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database="{{database}}", table_name="{{table_name}}")
df = DyF.toDF()
df.registerTempTable('{{name}}')
df = sqlContext.sql('{{your select query with table name that you used for temp table above}}')
df.write.format('{{orc/parquet/whatever}}').partitionBy("{{columns}}").save('path to s3 location')
```

Comment: Forgive me if the answer to this is obvious but I need to know: So I will just need to insert this df instead of the applymapping in the datasink and it should generate the out csv in s3? Or do I again have to create a dynamic frame from this data frame?

Comment: @RakeshGuha : I updated the sample code. Once you have applied all the transformations on DF using your sql queries, you can write the data back to S3 using df.write function. You don't need to convert the dataframe back to dynamic frame. As for applymapping, it is a dynamic frame specific function. You can convert the Dynamic Frame to DF post applymapping and then apply your sql query on DF.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try this and let you know. Thanks again!

Comment: line 32, in <module> df = sqlContext.sql('select QUERY') NameError: name 'sqlContext' is not defined End of LogType:stdout 

Again a basic question but does this sqlContext need to be defined? if so, how do we do that?

Comment: sqlContext = SQLContext(spark_session.sparkContext, spark_session) NameError: name 'spark_session' is not defined - still getting these errors for some reason

Comment: sqlContext = SQLContext(spark_session.SparkContext, spark_session) AttributeError: 'SparkSession' object has no attribute 'SparkContext' ---Still getting some issues, I'm sorry to bother you again and again regarding this.

Comment: No Problem. Please share your updated code. You can add the updated code in your question itself as it will be well formatted.

Comment: Also please note that, what I have shared is a python code snippet, not scala.

Comment: Your code worked! it was me who did a typo, apologies for that! I did everything you mentioned an it worked perfectly! Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

This is how I did it by converting the glue dynamic frame to spark dataframe first. Then using the glueContext object and sql method to do the query.

```py
spark_dataframe = glue_dynamic_frame.toDF()
spark_dataframe.createOrReplaceTempView("spark_df")

glueContext.sql("""
SELECT * 
FROM spark_df
LIMIT 10
""").show()
```